# Safari cookie in iframe

Tags: cookies, iframe, safari

Latest safari update block 3rd-party cookies in iframe. ( https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/ )

They offer several solutions to resolve it. I have tried to implement Storage Access API solution, but do like the result.

Can anyone give a hint or a sample flow without technical details on how to implement this:

```
Option 1: OAuth 2.0 Authorization with which the authenticating domain (in your case, the third-party 
that expects cookies) forwards an authorization token to your website which you consume and use to 
establish a first-party login session with a server-set Secure and HttpOnly cookie.
```

firstparty.com has 3rdparty.com in iframe. According to `option 1` 3rdparty.com authorize via OAuth, receive token. But what does it mean to "forward token to your website to establish login session"? Should 3rdparty.com run login routine as first-party in separate window?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

what they are referring to is still having the cookie be a first party (on your website). for example:

user follows this flow:

1. go to website.com
2. redirected to oauthSite.com for authentication
3. ouathSite.com redirects back to website.com with token (or code)
4. website.com sets token locally on server side code
5. user now has secure (https only) and HttpOnly (inaccessible to the JavaScript) cookie token that can be used for stateless interactions with website.com

This site seems to go thought the flows quite well:
https://medium.com/@darutk/diagrams-and-movies-of-all-the-oauth-2-0-flows-194f3c3ade85

Comment: but does it help me to have cookie in iframe? I still need site in iframe